# Increase render distance in HERE maps javascript api

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

I'm playing around with HERE maps JS API now for some days.
When using tilt of 60+ you can see the "end" of the view in the distance. Is it possible to increase this view distance a bit to load map tiles / buildings more far away then the distance fog?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you are looking for is not configurable.The Sky/fog view is part of the map and can be adjusted by adjusting the tilt.